# LWC - lightning-carousel-image - Set attribute behavior _blank

Tags: lightning-web-components

I need to open a image from the carousel in a new tab like target"_blank" in a  tag from html

I tried set target="_blank" with href in the  lightning-carousel-image and did not work

also

I tried to remove the attribute href from component and code the behavior in the onClick but I received the message SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } from event.target and 1 from event.detail than I could not get the related image src clicked.

Is there any alternative or need to create a whole custom carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly [do this dynamically](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/kTPOnVsQS7kg1tA5BeJb/src/app.html). Here's what that might look like:

```
<template>
    <lightning-carousel>
        <lightning-carousel-image data-target="_blank" alternative-text="Demo" href="https://www.google.com"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Sample_abc.jpg" onclick={handleClick}>
        </lightning-carousel-image>
        <lightning-carousel-image data-target="_blank" alternative-text="Demo" href="https://www.asdf.com"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Sample-image.svg" onclick={handleClick}>
        </lightning-carousel-image>
    </lightning-carousel>
    {clickTarget}
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  clickTarget;

  handleClick(event) {
    this.clickTarget = event.target.dataset.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open(event.target.href, event.target.dataset.target);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you!! This work perfectly!! Where is this concept about this value event.target.dataset.target where the dataset como from? Is there any document about this?

Comment: @MarcilioDevSfdc [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is where we can attach `data-*` attributes to an element, then use `dataset.*` to get those custom values.